# IIS 10 - Is there a setting to have IIS wait before restarting/recycling after file change is dectected?

Tags: iis, application-pool

I thought there was a setting that causes IIS to wait for some period of time before restarting when a file change is detected. Or something that would work similarly?

Comment: What file change? IIS doesn't monitor such, unless you are referring to ASP.NET AppDomain reload due to changes to files like `web.config`. But the latter is completely a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was thinking of the compilation optimizeCompilations setting.

Answer (score 0):

File changes are not the cause of application pool recycling. In addition to the default collection every 29 hours, the other way to allow the application pool to be recycled is to set a specific time or specific request amount or memory usage. It can also be recycled manually.

After the file is changed, the update is applied, not because the application pool is recycled, but the application is reloaded by IIS or ASP.NET, and w3wp.exe is always the same in the task manager.